# How do I debug Spring annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-data-rest

I have been using annotations on my Spring Boot project, and they are black boxes to me. Unfortunately, I ran into an issue with the annotations and had no idea how to track down the issue. I was using the `@PageableDefault` annotation on my controller method with the `@RepositoryRestController` annotation at the class level, which resulted in my `Pageable` object to be `null` under Spring Boot 1.4.1. If I used `@Controller`, my pageable object would be populated correct. This ended up being a bug [DATAREST-906](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-906) in Spring Data Rest and fixed in Spring Boot 1.4.2.

As a use case above what should I have done to debug this issue? Where should I have put my breakpoint to go down the rabbit hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the code that actually checks for the annotation and executes some logic based on it. This could theoretically happen in several places. If you search for occurrences of `WhateverAnnotation.class` in the source code you can find those places. You can also put breakpoints there, if you've linked the source properly in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks. So in this case I see an interface of `PageableDefault`, I assume `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is what handles the logic for the annotation? Where did `MappingAwarePageableArgumentResolver` from in the defect? I don't see it referenced.